# C# Excel (2003) interop - Margins don't correspond to the input value?

Tags: c#, excel, interop, margins

I'm using **dotNET C#** to communicate with **Excel 2003**. 
I'm trying to **change the print margins of the document**, but the values that I put in, don't correspond to the margin values that Excel then uses...

```
xls.PageSetup setup = ws.PageSetup;
setup.Orientation = xls.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape;

//Standard margins (Top - Bottom - Left - Right):
//                  2.5 - 2.5 - 1.9 - 1.9


setup.BottomMargin = 1.0;
setup.TopMargin = 1.0;
setup.LeftMargin = 1.0;
setup.RightMargin = 1.0;
//Excel gives me: 0.0 - 0.0 - 0.0 - 0.0

setup.BottomMargin = 20.0;
setup.TopMargin = 20.0;
setup.LeftMargin = 20.0;
setup.RightMargin = 20.0;
//Now Excel gives me: 0.7 - 0.7 - 0.7 - 0.7

setup.BottomMargin = 30.0;
setup.TopMargin = 30.0;
setup.LeftMargin = 30.0;
setup.RightMargin = 30.0;
//Now Excel gives me: 1.1 - 1.1 - 1.1 - 1.1
```

As you can see, Excel does change its margins, but it doesn't correspond to the double I'm putting in.
Is there a factor that I'm missing?

Many thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pagesetup.rightmargin(v=office.11).aspx

> Margins are set or returned in points. Use the [InchesToPoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.inchestopoints%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method or the [CentimetersToPoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.centimeterstopoints%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method to convert measurements from inches or centimeters.

Hope this helps